# What is the difference between explicit initialization and default initialization in a switch statement un-scoped case-labels?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

AFAIK it is not a good idea to define objects in a case-label without being scoped (surrounded with curly-braces) because control can bypass their definition:

1-

```
char grade = 'C';

switch (grade){
case 'A':
    std::cout << "grade A" << '\n';
    int n_elem = 0; // 
break;
case 'B': //  error: jump to case label
    std::cout << "grade A" << '\n';
    n_elem = 100;
break;
}
```

2-

```
char grade = 'C';

switch (grade){
case 'A':
    std::cout << "grade A" << '\n';
    int n_elem; // declaration or definition
break;
case 'B':
    std::cout << "grade A" << '\n';
    n_elem = 100; // ok
break;
}
```

- Why in 1 it doesn't work but in 2 it works?
- Why in 1 `n_elem` mustn't have an initializer but in 2 `n_elem` can be default-initialized?
- I guess in 1 and 2 `n_elem` is initialized what you think? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Nobody should write code like that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes and not me but I want to learn only why?

Comment: tl;dr : Proper initialization is a staple of C++. You can't skip initialization by jumping forward, compilers diagnose it. Only exception is when default initialization means no initialization. The value is already indeterminate, so jump all you want.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Sounds so interesting. What about a `static` object declaration their for example: `case 'a': int static n_elem; break; case 'b': break;`? a `static`  int is initialized to `0`. And the code works fine!

Comment: What about it? You asked and answered.